# To know about Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have my own ERP website.How can I use the Google Analytics What is best use of it
What's the optimal usage of Google Analytics for an ERP website?
What are the key uses of Google Analytics for an ERP website?
What are the main uses of Google Analytics for an ERP website?